# Multiple storyboards in a wpf application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have three storyboards in a wpf application.

begin is single animation
progress is a repeating animation
end is a single animation too

All storyboards animating the same image, the "progress" storyboard is repeating (while a query in an another thread is running), the "begin" storyboard preceeds it, the "end" animation follows it.
I supposed that this is a simple problem: when the application starts, start the "begin" animation, then in an oncompleted event handler, starts the progress animation, etc.

But it doesnt work: the progress animation is starts, but it appears improperly (strange flashing).

I made a "button1" to analyse this, and i noticed then the same method in the button's onclick eventhandler is works (after the begin storyboard is ended, i pushed it, and the progress storyboard is started and appeared perfectly).
(The FillBehavior of the begin animation is "Stop": the button doesnt worked without this setting, but the eventhandler is remains wrong after setting it)

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        begin = (Storyboard)FindResource("startanimation");
        progress = (Storyboard)FindResource("progressanimation");
        end = (Storyboard)FindResource("stopanimation");
        begin.Completed += new EventHandler(begin_Completed);
        begin.Begin();
    }


    void begin_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Begin();       //not works
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        progress.Begin();       //works
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void begin_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{          
     this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                            new Action(
                            delegate()
                            {
                                progress.Begin();
                            }
                        ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried it, but doesn't works, the flashing is still the same. Are they overlaps each other, or other strange thing... I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I am forced to make a secondary timer, and start the progress animation in the tick event.. Very ugly, but works.

Any other tips are still welcome.